# document.getElementById('blah').value not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

Is there any situation where I would have to set the focus on a input text first (`document.getElementById('the_input_text').focus()` )
before I could set the value (`document.getElementById('the_input_text').value='123'`) in order for me to see the value (123) in the input text?

I'm only asking because I have to do that on this page that I'm working on in order for me to see the value in the input text.

Comment: No. http://jsfiddle.net/sWjuW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no case where you need to focus the element first…unless there is some horribly-written, separate JavaScript repeatedly hard-setting the value until or unless focused.

You might try:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('the_input_text').value='123'
},2000);
```

…to see if there is JS that was overriding your values after setting them.

*I've tested to ensure that the HTML5 `placeholder="..."` attribute does not cause a problem with this.*